# How to remove empty space inside div?

Tags: html, css

Hello I am trying to get rid of a big empty space inside a div. It is between a title and a table, so there is a div, a table within a div and I'm trying to move the table up to cover the big space shown at the top. Anyone know what is wrong? [image: example] Literally the table is down below, and I want to move it up to cover the empty space which I don't want.

```css
<style>
    body {
        background-color: rgb(184, 130, 255);
        background-size: cover;
    }

    b {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        color: rebeccapurple;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 65px;
        font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: rgb(254, 253, 255);
    }

    a {
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    u {
        font-size: 34px;
        color: navy;
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    li {
        float: left;
    }

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    li a:hover:not(.active) {
        background-color: #111;
    }

    .active {
        background-color: #04AA6D;
    }

    div {
        border: 2px outset rgb(10, 9, 9);
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        max-width: 1200px;
        height: 4545px;
        padding: 2px;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }


    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 1px;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<body>
    <center>
        <p>Art by Arashjot</p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <center>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="Aboutme.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a class="active" href="art.html">Work</a></li>
            </ul>
        </center>

        <br>
        <br>
        <div>
            
            <br>
            <b>Here are a list of links to my artwork:</b>
            <table>
                <th><u>Games and Galore</u></th><br>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="images/Tetris_1.png" width="600px" height="280px">
                    </td><br>
                    <td><a href="tetris.html">The Matrix: Tetris resurrected</a></td><br>
                    <td><a>First year 2020, coded tetris game</a></td>
                </tr>
                <br>
                <tr>
                    <th><img src="images/narrative game.png" width="600px" height="280px"></th><br>
                    <td><a href="Coronaviral.html">Game Design</a></td><br>
                    <td><a>First year 2020, narrative game</a></td> <br>
                </tr>

                <th> <img src="images/documentation.png" width="600px" height="280px"></th><br>
                <td><a href="Unity.html">Unity Game Documentation</a></td><br>
                <td> <a>First year 2021, unity Game</a></td> <br>
                </tr>
                <br>

                <th><u>Animations and Adventures</u></th><br>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="images/animation.png" width="600px" height="280px">
                    </td><br>
                    <td><a href="pictures/final.mp4">My Work: Animation</a></td> <br>
                    <td><a>First year 2019, Animation</a></td>
                </tr>
                <br>
                <br>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="images/butterflies.png" width="600px" height="280px"><br></td>
                    <td><a href="assignment3.html">Monarchs</a></td> <br>
                    <td><a>First year 2020, coded butterflies</a></td>
                </tr><br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="images/universe.png" width="600px" height="280px"></td><br>
                    <td><a href="assign4.html">Planets and Galaxies</a></td> <br>
                    <td><a>First year 2020, universe</a></td> <br>
                </tr>
                <br>
                <br>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="images/childhood.png" width="600px" height="280px"></td><br>
                    <td><a href="feb192020.html">Childhood Magic!</a></td> <br>
                    <td><a>First year 2019, coded childhood</a></td> <br>
                </tr>
                <br>
                <br>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="images/worlds.png" width="600px" height="280px"></td><br>
                    <td><a href="Homepage.html">DREAMSPACE</a></td><br>
                    <td><a>Second year 2021, worlds of worlds escape</a></td> <br>
                </tr>
                <br>


                <th><u>Personal Artifacts</u></th><br>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="images/personal.png" width="600px" height="280px">
                    </td><br>
                    <td><a href="Assignment.html">Personal Work</a></td> <br>
                    <td><a>Hobbies and Artwork</a></td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <br>
                <br>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="images/behance.png" width="600px" height="280px">
                    </td><br>
                    <td><a href="https://www.behance.net/arashjotkaur">Behance Profile: Personal Hobby</a></td><br>
                    <td><a>Dedicated to MCU </a></td>
                </tr>
                <br>
                <br>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="images/projectme.png" width="600px" height="280px">
                <br>
                <td><a href="https://bellayamazaki15.wixsite.com/my-site-3/project-me-video">Project me device</a></td>
                <td><a>Second year 2020, a Thing from the Future</a></td>
                </tr>
                <br>
                <br>
                <tr>
                <td><img src="images/folktales.png" width="600px" height="280px"></td><br>
                <td><a href="https://rhepa15.wixsite.com/folktales">Cultural Traditions</a></td><br>
                <td><a>Second year 2021, New Years Folktales</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please check your html code, it shows multiple errors

Comment: The problem is your 47 `<br/>` tags (yes, i counted) that come from the table. You cannot insert `<br/>` to display spaces in your table other than inside the `<td>` tag. Any `<br/>` tag that is not inside a `<td>` ends up between your title and the table - To insert empty spaces, use `<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>`